# is it possible to save data of my customized application in visual force workbook to my own database with out using salesforce database

Tags: rest

I created one application in salesforce.com.That application contains create,Update,delete,GetList buttons.Is it possible to save data in to mysql database(my local database) when user clicks these buttons.If it is possible,please tell me the procedure how to implement.

Thanks
Anuradha

Answer (score 1):

Yes this could be done.

From an Apex controller you can access both SOAP and REST webservices. You'd need to create either of those in a language and system of your choice that will expose access to your database.

Though this is a very broad question, highlighting every pitfall and possible sub-question should not be seen as in scope of this question.